# MVVM и многопоточность

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Подскажите, в каких ситуациях нужно использовать диспетчер в MVVM приложении?

Если в WindowsForms все понятно- используй тогда, когда хочешь присвоить значение элементу, находясь в другом потоке, то в WPF немного непонятно, так как все за кулисами само биндится и все такое и явного обращения к элементам нету.

Comment: всё точно так же - при обращении из другого потока

Comment: Т.е, если я находясь в другом потоке меняю забинженное где-то свойство, то должен использовать диспетчер?

Comment: Если вы использовали что-то из Task - да, должны.

Comment: Все свойства, к которым есть привязки должны обновляться в потоке GUI. Т.е. VM бежит в потоке GUI. Вот и вся история.

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле, у каждого контрола и у диспетчера есть специальный метод, который уточняет, требуется ли выполнять работу через диспетчер. Например в каком нибудь `OnPropertyChanged` я обычно делаю вот так:

```
if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
  PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
else
  Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => 
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)));
```

Тогда, в случае если свойство было изменено в не UI потоке - вызов будет перекинут в UI поток, иначе выполнен прямо в текущем. Никаких проблем с внезапными ошибками, что нельзя биндить в чужом потоке больше не увидел.

Answer (score -1):

Cледуюящая [статья](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/dn630646.aspx) от самих Microsoft разъясняет общее использование многопоточности в MVVM. Там же затронут и Dispatcher.

Comment: Ужаснейшая статья, которая до краев наполнена переусложненными примерами...

Comment: Каждому своё - для меня было доходчиво. А так, конечно, материалов на русском не столь много по данной теме. Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354438/how-to-pass-the-ui-dispatcher-to-the-viewmodel) более предметно.